# Is radius always constant in a uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, angular-velocity

Somehow I would like to know whether the radius must be constant in a uniform circular motion. If it is not constant, is the motion called non-uniform circular motion or neither?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about geometry (the definition of a circle) not physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the radius is always constant in uniform (non-uniform) circular motion. A circle has a constant radius, by definition. If the radius isn’t constant, it isn’t circular motion.

Comment: So, will it be curvilinear motion if the radius keeps changing?

Comment: Generally. But it could also be linear.

Comment: Moreover, does it mean that a motion will become circular motion again once its radius attains equilibrium? And at the moment that the radius is attaining the equilibrium means it is not in circular motion.

Comment: That depends on the details of the dynamics. For example, the orbit of a planet around the Sun stays an ellipse. There is nothing making its non-constant radius “attain equilibrium”.